# connect to mysql database server in Windows from Vagrant box

Tags: mysql, vagrant

I installed mysql server 5.6, and I can connect to it using mysql workbench, but I'm wondering if I can connect to it from Vagrant box, and I tried the following command, but failed:

```
vagrant@sdi03:~$ mysql -h 127.0.0.1 --port=3366 -u root -p
Enter password:
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)
```

Note that I purposely run the mysql server on port 3366 instead of 3306, because I have another mysql server running on Vagrant box on port 3306.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using success connect to ip adress of my windows, it's 192.168.1.55

```
mysql -u konst -p -h 192.168.1.55
```

PS I can't connect with *root*, i create new mysqluser *konst* with admin's rights